# Using profiles in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2e

I have added below profile to my pom.xml :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>nexusid1</id>
                   <url>http://</url>
            </repository>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>nexusid2</id>
                 <url>http://</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
        </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have added to settings.xml :

```
    <server>
<id>nexusid1</id>
<username>username</username>
<password>passwword</password>
    </server>
```

To add the project to the Nexus repo I use `mvn deploy`

Do I need to use a profile in this case ?
If I want to deploy to nexusid2 does this mean I need to add a new server entry to settings.xml even if the username/password for nexusid1 & nexusid2 are the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository), there is a `-DaltDeploymentRepository` argument for `mvn:deploy`. But imho, profiles would be the more elegant solution here, cause you don't need to remember the server id but the profile name.
And yes, you need to add a new server to the settings.xml, even if username and password are equal.

Note besides: [Password encryption for server management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I configure it to deploy to nexusid2 ? Currently it just deploys to nexusid1 because I have a corresponding server entry in settings.xml. Do I just need to add the server entry for nexusid2 ? If this is the case can I deploy to just a specific server repo

Comment: Afaik is there no way to specify multiple repos for deploy, except the mentioned profiles. So you need two profiles, one for each server, with the matching entries in settings.xml. If you want to deploy to a specific server only, it would be the best to define these two profiles, but don't use one of them as default, so you can specify the server-profiles you want to deploy to.